# Pass $_GET variable with .load and load a specific page fragment

Tags: javascript, get, load, fragment

I'm trying to put two things together:

```
$('#result').load('liste_result #mainDiv');
```

and

```
$('#result').load("liste_result?q=" + $("#categorie").val());
```

Both of these work, separetly. But I'm trying to put them together now, so pass a variable and only load a particular div. But I can't seem to get it working, this is my code:

```
$('#result').load("liste_result?q=" + $("#categorie").val()"#mainDiv");
```

How should I put it to get it to work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Missing a `+` on the third example.

Comment: Where does the + miss? Thanks.

Comment: There is a syntax error before "#mainDiv". See Mehdi's answer. That's probably what you want.

Comment: Well it isn't what I want actually, because it only sends mainDiv as a variable. What I want is to follow this code:
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
While adding a variable! This code only selects the <div> container on the external page.

Comment: See my answer. That may be what you want. Not too familiar with the .load function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
$('#result').load("liste_result?q=" + $("#categorie").val() + " #mainDiv");
```

But I'm not too familiar with $.load().

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect, exactly what I want. Is something wrong in the method I'm using, then? I thought it was pretty logic what I was doing, but Mehdi seems to think it isn't! Thanks anyways.

Comment: You almost had it. You just had a syntax error. I think there was confusion in what "#mainDiv" was. I didn't know about putting an element selector after the URL in the same string.

Comment: I didn't know either, well I've just started using Jquery, AJAX and stuff, so still learning it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you are trying to accomplish but it probably should be like this :

```
$('#result').load("liste_result?q=" + $("#categorie").val() + $("#mainDiv").val());
```

However you should be aware that your query `q` could have spaces in it, and I don't understand why you are sending html to the server.

**UPDATE :**
To answer your comment about a external link not sure you can do it if you are not querying from the same domain, the syntax should be like this then :

```
$('#result').load("liste_result?q=" + $("#categorie").val() + " #mainDiv");
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I want. All I want is to load an external page, while passing a variable, and only loading a particular <div> from that external page. That div being mainDiv.
On the Ajax wiki they say this it the syntax:
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
But that doesn't include giving a variable. Your code doesn't select the mainDiv div, it only sends it as a variable.
Thanks for the help!